# Duda con UML (Relacion ternaria)

Tags: sql, uml

Tengo una duda con un enunciado para pasar a UML y dudas con las relaciones ternarias debido a como está expresado,dice así:

> Puede ocurrir que algún deportista esté federado. De hecho, un deportista puede estar asociado a ninguna, una o varias federaciones deportivas. Por cada federación a la que esté asociado, se desea almacenar en la base de datos el número de licencia federativa. También es posible que haya clubes federados, en cuyo caso, se desea también conocer la federación correspondiente. Se sabe que no se van a almacenar en la base de datos federaciones para las que no haya ningún deportista federado, si bien se pueden registrar federaciones sin ningún club federado.

Lo que yo hice fue esto pero tengo dudas de que sea una relación ternaria entre federación,deportistas y club:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que podría meter una ternaria aquí pero tengo dudas en sus relaciones, por muchas que le doy no lo veo claro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo es que no acabo de ver la relación ternaria. Por un lado van los deportistas y por otro los clubes. De hecho, en ningún momento mencionas ninguna relación entre deportistas y clubes. Lo que veo que falta en tu esquema son las tablas que representen las relaciones `asocian` pues, como tienen cardinalidad N:N, no las puedes omitir. Ante la duda, intenta registrar un dato ficticio. Es la mejor forma de ver si se almacena correctamente o no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bueno parece que voy teniendo claras las cosas después de hacer tantos jejeje. Gracias por los consejos y aclaraciones!

Comment: Poco a poco... pero oye, que en éste tampoco es que yo esté totalmente convencido. Ya me cuentas qué te dicen sobre él. De entrada, que los deportistas no se inscriban en clubes, se me hace raro... Pero oye, las cuestiones académicas a veces son así: irreales... Igual lo ponen para que no vayáis directamente a relaciones ternarias

Comment: jejeje pues ya te comentaré que me dicen ;)